# Dynamic Color Palettes - Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone have any suggestions for creating dynamic color palettes?

We are creating a site which has contains various client areas - the brief is to allow clients to be able to personalise the look and feel of these areas themselves via a settings menu and choosing spot colors - we dont want them to be able to choose all the spot colours as it could easily look awful - so we would like to allow one spot color selection and have a Jquery Algorithm or something similar which could create complementary color palettes for the additional colors required.

Is this possible?  Has anyone ever seen anything like this or could you push me in the right direction anyhow?

Cheers

Comment: [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or other CSS "extensions" is the best way to do it.

Comment: @paul I'm waiting for an answer! +1

Comment: Cheers JamWaffles - had no idea LESS had that functionality - I'll have a play with it.. cheers - check it out @sємsєм (http://lesscss.org/#-color-functions)

Answer (score 0):

http://lesscss.org/

or

http://sass-lang.com/

Both are fantastic dynamic stylesheet languages. Also you will need a compiler for local dev. I prefer to use http://incident57.com/codekit/